# ActiveMQ broker error "Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination trying to recover. Cause: The Consumer is closed"

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

We have observed in our enviornment as consumer from ActiveMQ UI get removed. We have very low traffic and observed as initially we have 3 consumer and those got each of them removed after interval of couple hours and once we restart our consumer it again refresh connection for couple more hours, we dont see any error in logs except:

```
Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue-1' - trying to recover. Cause: The Consumer is closed
```

I use AWS ActiveMQ broker and don't see any error in the broker logs.

We use `PoolConnectionFactory` with `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` for creating pool of connection for our consumer as recommended. we are using ActiveMQ 5.15

```java
@Bean
public PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory =
            new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setUserName(username);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setPassword(password);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
    ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy activeMQPrefetchPolicy = new ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy();
    activeMQPrefetchPolicy.setQueuePrefetch(100);
    //activeMQPrefetchPolicy.setQueuePrefetch();
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setPrefetchPolicy(activeMQPrefetchPolicy);
    PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory);
    pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(poolSize);
    return pooledConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
            new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(pooledConnectionFactory());
    factory.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter());
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    factory.setConcurrency("1-1");
    factory.setErrorHandler(ActiveMQErrorHandler());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(pooledConnectionFactory());
    jmsTemplate.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter());
    return jmsTemplate;
}

@Bean
public Queue queue() {
    return new ActiveMQQueue(queueName);
}

@Bean
public ErrorHandler ActiveMQErrorHandler() {
    return t -> {
        LOGGER.error("JMS_LISTENER_ERROR");
    };
}
```

Comment: @JustinBertram i use aws active mq broker and dont see any error in broker , in ActiveMQHandler just logging logs  , dont see printed same in logs  `@Bean
    public ErrorHandler ActiveMQErrorHandler() {return t ->{ LOGGER.error("JMS_LISTENER_ERROR");}; }`

Comment: we need to make consumer connected even if there is traffic or no traffic , we tried idletimeout with higher value but that also did not help

Comment: Is it possible there is a network device (e.g. firewall) that is closing the idle connection?

Comment: @JustinBertram I dont think so as with 3 consumer running only 2 went down after 24 hours , 1 consumer is still running from last 3 days even if there is no traffic , is there a configuration i am missing in active mq consumer setting to make sure consumer always connected to broker ?

Comment: What is the connection URI you are using to create the pooled connections?

Comment: We call R53 -> NLB -> AWS MQ IP for port 61617 , so it will be ssl://r53:61617

Answer (score 1):

Given the information provided it sounds as though either the connection is dropping and the client isn't reporting that or the remote is closing the consumer on it's end which the pool will likely not notice until some user action is performed.

This is one of the gotchas of using a JMS pool which is that the pool doesn't have complete insight into what is going on with the client and therefore checking out a connection that's been sitting in the pool can result in obtaining a stale and no longer active connection due to the IO interruption that doesn't bubble up to the pool layer.  One means of working around this would be to use the ActiveMQ client failover transport to allow it to automatically reconnect to the broker if the connection is dropped.

Another option you could try is to use the [PooledJMS](https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms) JMS connection pooling library which has some additional work done to attempt to validate failed connections and or closed resources sooner and match that with a ConnectionFactory that creates ActiveMQ connection's that use failover so that remotely closed resources like consumers could be caught in some cases.

Ultimately though your code will still need to deal with potential failure cases out of the JMS resources and retry where needed such as senders seeing security exceptions etc.  The pooling bits don't make all your troubles go away, and in some cases they just introduce new one's you hadn't thought of yet.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info , As message listeners are long running there isn't much benefit to using a connection out of a connection pool so removed connection pool mapping for listener MQ connection-factory and to let the
container manage it , we don't see consumer did not down at least from last 24 hours.